# Permission denied (publickey) from ec2 to github

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, github, ssh

Please note: I first log in into my ec2 server with ssh.

Then I created a new ssh key. Generating it gave me these files:

```
id_ed25519.pub
id_ed25519
```

I opened the setting page at github and added a new ssh-key.
I entered the content of "id_ed25519.pub".

I go back to my ec2 instance and run this command:

```
git clone git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git
```

What I get is this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I run this:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

then I get this message:

```
Hello username. You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Why am I not able to clone the repo?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running `ssh -Tv git@github.com` from the same ECS environment you are attempting your clone, said clone should work.

You can compare the `ssh -Tv git@github.com` output (which works) with your git clone by doing:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
git clone git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git
```

You will see if the git clone use attempting to use the same keys as your ssh did.

Comment: Thanks, but when I run git clone, nothing is printed regarding the used key. Actually, it is still showing the same error text (permission denied) without any verbose info about the used key. And yes, I first run the export-command.

Comment: @oderfla What version of Git is used in that environment? What `git version` return?

Comment: It is git version 2.38.1

Comment: @oderfla OK, can you try `git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -Tv" clone git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git`? (using the [config `core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand))